# Matlab r2013a doesn't recognize any compiler in order to protect a model

Tags: simulink, matlab-compiler

I have a problem with my r2013a Matlab.

I want to protect a model  using Simulink.ModelReference.protect('test')  command. For this 
I have to configure my compiler. I'm using the mex -setup command, and the xpcsetCC -setup command.

At first, Matlab says that is all ok with the compiler, but when i try to execute the Simulink.ModelReference.protect('model') command it shows an erro saying that there is no compiler avaiable.
Here are the sequences of commands:

## PART 1 - 'mex -setup'

INPUT

```
mex -setup
```

OUTPUT

```
Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up  
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/win64.html 

Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n?
```

INPUT

```
   y
```

OUTPUT

```
 Select a compiler: 
 [1] Intel C++ 12.0 (with Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) linker) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\ 
 [2] Intel C++ 12.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 linker) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011 
 [3] Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 
 [4] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 

 [0] None 

 Compiler:
```

INPUT

```
 4
```

OUTPUT

```
 Please verify your choices: 

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
```

Are these correct [y]/n?

INPUT

```
y
```

OUTPUT

```
*************************************************************************** 
  Warning: MEX-files generated using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 require 
           that Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 run-time libraries be  
           available on the computer they are run on. 
           If you plan to redistribute your MEX-files to other MATLAB 
           users, be sure that they have the run-time libraries. 
*************************************************************************** 


Trying to update options file: C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2013a\mexopts.bat 
From template:              C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc100opts.bat 

Done . . . 

************************************************************************** 
  Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB 
           variables with more than 2^32-1 elements.  In the near future 
           you will be required to update your code to utilize the new 
           API. You can find more information about this at: 
           http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html  
           Building with the -largeArrayDims option enables the new API. 
**************************************************************************
```

## PART 2 - 'xpcsetCC -setup'

INPUT

```
xpcsetCC -setup
```

OUTPUT

```
 Select your compiler for xPC Target.


  [1] Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers 2010 Professional in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0

  [0] None


  Compiler:
```

INPUT

```
1
```

OUTPUT

```
Verify your selection:

  Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers 2010 Professional
  Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0

  Are these correct [y]/n?Y

  Done...
```

Until now everthing is ok, but next there is an error:

## Part 3 -  Simulink.ModelReference.protect('test')

INPUT

```
 Simulink.ModelReference.protect('test')
```

OUTPUT

```
### Model reference SIM target (test_msp.mexw64) for model test is out of date because test_msp.mexw64 does not exist.
### Updating model reference SIM target for model: test
Warning: The model 'test' does not have continuous states, hence Simulink is using the solver 'VariableStepDiscrete' instead of solver 'ode45'.
You can disable this diagnostic by explicitly specifying a discrete solver in the solver tab of the Configuration Parameters dialog, or by
setting the 'Automatic solver parameter selection' diagnostic to 'none' in the Diagnostics tab of the Configuration Parameters dialog 
Warning: Using a default value of 0.2 for maximum step size.  The simulation step size will be equal to or less than this value.  You can disable
this diagnostic by setting 'Automatic solver parameter selection' diagnostic to 'none' in the Diagnostics page of the configuration parameters
  dialog 
  ### Build procedure for model: 'test' aborted due to an error.
  Error using Creator.protect (line 287)
  An installed compiler was not detected. Certain simulation modes, as well as host-based coder builds require that a compiler be installed. Please
  install one of the supported compilers for this release as listed at:

  http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/win64.html

  MATLAB must be restarted after the compiler is installed.

  Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\simulink\simulink\+Simulink\+ModelReference\protect.p>protect (line 74)
  [harnessHandle, neededVars] = protectedModelCreator.protect(varargin{:});
```

I've already tried all different choices of available compilers. I also tried to choose no for the fist question of `mex -setup` ("Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n?") and choose the compiler manually. None of this worked.

Comment: What does `cc = mex.getCompilerConfigurations` return? The compiler set up for xPC has nothing to do with the one used for creating protected models. Try running the `timestwo` MEX file example in http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html to check your compiler is correctly installed. It may be that the compiler path is not on your computer PATH environment variable.